# Unit Test to verify content of IEnumerable<dynamic>

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dynamic

Given the following WebAPI method:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetDeliveryTypes()
{
    return Ok(... .Select(dt => new { Id = dt.Id, Name = dt.Name }));
}
```

Where

```
typeof(Id) = long  
typeof(Name) = string
```

While unit testing, how can I

1. Assert that the content is as I expect it? For example, the following assertion fails

   ```
   var contentResult = response as OkNegotiatedContentResult<IEnumerable<dynamic>>;
   Assert.IsNotNull(contentResult);
   ```
2. Reduce this `IEnumerable<dynamic>` result to an `IEnumerable<long>` so I can verify that it contains the expected sequence of values?

I have already added the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute to the AssemblyInfo.

Comment: At least the second point won´t work at all I guess, because your `dynamic`-instances are actually of type `anonamouys { long, string }`, not `long`, arent´t they?

Comment: That's exactly right, @HimBromBree. This is why I'm wondering what the type specified to `OkNegotiatedContentResult` should be.

Comment: As you´re already stuck on `dynamic` why don´t use it any further and make `response` of type `dynamic` also by simply casting to `danymic` instead of `OkNegotiated...`?

Answer (score 3):

**1.** Something to start with:

```
response.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(OkNegotiatedContentResult<>)
```

You can continue type investigation from here if you want.

**2.** The solution for second point is pretty easy:

```
dynamic response = controller.GetDeliveryTypes();
Assert.True(response.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(OkNegotiatedContentResult<>));
var content = (IEnumerable<dynamic>)response.Content;
var ids = content.Select(i => i.Id).ToList();
```

If the tests are in separate assembly - add `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("TestAssembly")]` as anonymous types are generated as internal.

Comment: In point 2, `IHttpActionResult` does not have a property `Content`, nor does `dynamic` (as you've declared it).

Comment: That's the point - [dynamic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) is assumed to support any operation. Once I've checked that response is `OkNegotiatedContentResult<>` I'm sure that it has `Content` property. Try it - it works.

Comment: `RuntimeBinderException: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Content'` - this is thrown on the 3rd line.

Comment: Strange - works fine on my side. And type assert passed?

Comment: The type assert passed only after I had included a reference to `Microsoft.CSharp`. Could there be another assembly needing referenced?

Comment: OK - your tests are in separate assembly and anonymous types are generated as internal. Add `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("TestAssembly")]`

Comment: Already added the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute - as noted at the end of the OP.

Comment: Verify that `InternalsVisibleTo` works - try to add `internal` type in web api project and access it in tests project

Comment: The problem isn't that the type isn't recognised - the problem is that `Content` is not a property of `dynamic`, unless an extension is available in an additional assembly.

Comment: You're wrong, I've reproduced this exception and `InternalsVisibleTo` fixed it. Just to confirm this - put test code in the web api assembly and try.

Comment: Well this is embarrassing: I misspelt the name of the test project in the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute. You're right, it works now. Thanks for sticking with me.

Answer (score 0):

I just used reflection to get the Content property.

```
var response = controller.GetDeliveryTypes();

Assert.IsNotNull(response);
object content = response
  .GetType()
  .GetProperty("Content")
  .GetValue(response);
```